# BroadcastReceiver does not trigger

Tags: android

i have a `public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` and an Activity with the following part in its `onCreate`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 5000, pintent);
    } else {
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+5000, pintent);
    }
```

So, the `onReceive` method of my `AlarmReceiver`should be called 5seconds after this code is executed, shouldn't it? But it isn't, i've waited a few minutes but nothing happens. And yes i have added `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>` to my manifest.
(My phone executes `setExact`)

Comment: Do you have the Receiver listed in the manifest? Also, you don't need the `SET_ALARM` permission for this.

Comment: ah of course... forgot that. Pity that this doesn't give an error like when i try to start an activity that is not listed there. Why don't i need the permission? What is it for then?

Comment: The `SET_ALARM` permission is needed for using an `Intent` to set an alarm with an alarm clock app. Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html).

Comment: ok, ty. I know this doesn't bleong here, but can u tell me, how to put and get extras in the intent? I tried putting it into `intent`, but the `intent`  from the argument of `onReceive`doesn't have it

Comment: Well, that's how you do it. Make sure you're using the same keys to put and to get your extras, and that you're getting them as the right types. Also, `PendingIntent`s can be reused, so if the extras just aren't updating, you'll have to change something to make them; i.e., different request codes for each `PendingIntent`, different actions for each `Intent`, an appropriate flag for the `getBroadcast()` call's last argument, etc. That is really a different question, though.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to make sure that you have created a broadcastreceiver properly is to to add it through the context menu. In that way, the receiver will also be added to the manifest accordingly.

[image: Adding a new broadcastreceiver]
[image: Adding a new broadcastreceiver#2]